# How to write the flash memory of stm32w108 from code

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, contiki, linker-scripts

I am working on a problem, where I need to read and write some data from the flash of stm32w108 microcontroller. I am using dizic mb954 board, and running contiki on it. I've tried modifying the linker script by adding an extra section .flash_store within the .text section and added **(rwx)** attribute to the flash, and explicitly declared an array using

`__attribute__((.flash_store))`

The problem is although I can read the initialized array properly, while writing, it falls back to the default handler and loops there.

In AVR microcontrollers this is easily done using PROGMEM attribute, is there any similar workaround for stm32w108?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you will have to have a look at the user guide of your microcontroller and search for the flash peripheral. The flash peripheral will allow you to write flash at run-time. You might have to code methods such as:

```
bool flash_write(void *to, void *from, size_t size)
{
  // unlock flash access
  // erase flash
  // write the new data
  // lock flash access
}
```

Check out the "Programming Manual" at http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/CD00280769.pdf and head to Section 2.2. I think that's what you are looking for.

Probably you will find some user library with already built-in flash routines.

Good luck!